# Images in RoboVM

Tags: ios, robovm

I'm using robovm and want to display a number of images I receive remotely in UIImage. There are two ways to get images (and this cannot be changed since they come from another source). Some are sent in as JPEG and some as pixels in int array. Now, the int images converted to UIImage refuse to draw into image context like here,

```
    NSData imgData = new NSData(array);
    CGDataProvider provider = CGDataProvider.create(imgData);
    CGImage img = CGImage.create((long) size.getWidth(), (long) size.getHeight(),
                8, 32, (long) (size.getWidth()) * 4, CGColorSpace.createDeviceRGB(), new CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.value()),
                provider, null, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
    UIGraphics.beginImageContext(size);
    fullscreen.draw(CGPoint.Zero(), CGBlendMode.Normal, 1.0);
    UIImage uimg = new UIImage(img);
    uimg.draw(new CGRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height), CGBlendMode.Normal, 1.0);
    fullscreen = UIGraphics.getImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.endImageContext();
```

But it shows up properly when done like this:

```
    NSData imgData = new NSData(array);
    CGDataProvider provider = CGDataProvider.create(imgData);
    CGImage img = CGImage.create((long) size.getWidth(), (long) size.getHeight(),
                8, 32, (long) (size.getWidth()) * 4, CGColorSpace.createDeviceRGB(), new CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.value()),
                provider, null, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
    fullscreen = new UIImage(img);
```

However in this case I can't show the images alongside JPEGs since it would require drawing first the background. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int array needs to be put through this loop before being turned into CGImage:

```
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = pixels[i] | 0xff000000;
    }
```

Because on default the alpha (top byte) is zero and image is not visible.